# What are advantages of using babel-plugin-react-intl?

Tags: react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I've been trying to learn and understand `react-intl` library and I encountered `babel-plugin-react-intl` library. There is a description in the library's page like that;

`Extracts string messages for translation from modules that use React Intl.`

I wonder that which string messages would be extracted?

Also, what are the benefits of extracted messages?

Answer (score 5):

From: https://blog.johnphoto.se/2016/03/21/react-intl-v2/ (couldn't comment without more rep)

> Once it is time to get all these messages translated, you only have to
>   do a webpack build with the  babel-plugin react-intl plugin. This will
>   extract all the defined messages from the code base into JSON files.
>   These files are then sent to your translators and they translate all
>   of these messages and the translations is put into a flat JSON hash
>   and this is then loaded into your code and you have a i18n enabled
>   app. So enough with theory!

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I am using babel-plugin-react-intl to automatically extract all the labels in my React application.
I'd point as main advantages the following two:

1. Using the plugin, all the labels from my application are automatically extracted to json files. Instead of having to manually update the json files that will be translated. This way, I don't need to worry about this file, as the plugin will push the labels to it.
2. If I accidentally create a duplicated ID for a label, the plugin tells me that by throwing an error on webpack.

Extra: I am not using, but, if you want to force developers to add a context description for each label, this plugin also has an option to force this behavior so that, if the developer forgets it, an error is thrown on webpack.